Object add no showing to event add_to_cart
I am trying to integrate Woocommerce with Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics and Google ADS.
When I try to configure add_to_cart event, I don't know because no show this object "add" in my dataLayer.
I don't know what product has been add in my cart, because no show in my data_layer, just the same items to my view_page event.
I use gt4mtwp Plugin to Woocommerce, below this configuration:
Configuration Plugin
OBS: The last item that i add to cart is item_name = Diciclo Elétrico DROP PRO 8.5 (Mostruário), and your quantity is declared below.
Other products in my cart:
item_name: Cod. 28655 - Farol p/ Bike Sixties e Cruiser Drop
item_name: Cod. 32421 - Carburador p/ Moto T-Rex Drop

DataLayer of the add_to_cart event
event: "add_to_cart",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: 34, start: 1714052026601},
  ecommerce: {
    currency: "BRL",
    value: 2490,
    items: [
      {
        item_id: 24064,
        item_name: "Diciclo Elétrico DROP PRO 8.5 (Mostruário)",
        sku: "27413M",
        price: "2490.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "instock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Semi-Novos",
        id: 24064,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 3,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: "",
        quantity: "1"
      },
      {
        item_id: 22873,
        item_name: "Patinete Elétrico DROP JETTER 48v (Mostruário)",
        sku: "32669M",
        price: "6990.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "instock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Patinete Elétrico",
        id: 22873,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 5,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 7784,
        item_name: "PROMOÇÃO: LEVE EM DOBRO - Pneu 8x3.00 MaxxiGrip S" +
                   "lick",
        sku: "28",
        price: "108.00",
        stocklevel: 1026,
        stockstatus: "instock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Promoções",
        id: 7784,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 7,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 20635,
        item_name: "Patinete Elétrico DROP GO-08 350W-36v (Mostruário)",
        sku: "33779M",
        price: "3990.00",
        stocklevel: 0,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Semi-Novos",
        id: 20635,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 9,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 23877,
        item_name: "Diciclo Elétrico DROP RAVEBOARD (Usado)",
        sku: 23877,
        price: "1490.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Semi-Novos",
        id: 23877,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 11,
        product_type: "variable",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 24764,
        item_name: "Patinete Elétrico DROP GO-KIDS 150W-24v (Mostruár" +
                   "io)",
        sku: 24764,
        price: "2490.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "instock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Semi-Novos",
        id: 24764,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 13,
        product_type: "variable",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 22880,
        item_name: "kart DROP HOVERKART PRO (Mostruário)",
        sku: 22880,
        price: "3990.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Semi-Novos",
        id: 22880,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 15,
        product_type: "variable",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 19991,
        item_name: "Pneu 200x50 Runner",
        sku: "31",
        price: "60.00",
        stocklevel: 0,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Promoções",
        id: 19991,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 17,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 25836,
        item_name: "Patinete Elétrico DROP GO-E10PRO 500W-48v (Semino" +
                   "vo)",
        sku: "31515S",
        price: "4490.00",
        stocklevel: 0,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Patinete",
        id: 25836,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 19,
        product_type: "simple",
        item_brand: ""
      },
      {
        item_id: 27604,
        item_name: "COMBO Hover KART PRO + Diciclo Elétrico DROP PRO " +
                   "8.5 (Mostruário)",
        sku: 27604,
        price: "5980.00",
        stocklevel: null,
        stockstatus: "outofstock",
        google_business_vertical: "retail",
        item_category: "Diciclo",
        id: 27604,
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        index: 21,
        product_type: "variable",
        item_brand: ""
      }
    ]
  }

I try alternate plugin configuration, but don't have success in my tests.
Search in Youtube channels and blogs if other people have the same problem, but never.
